# Return true if two or more repeated chars

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

The regular expressions I have tried include following:

```
      1> var temp = "(.)\\1{2,}";
      2> var temp = "^(?!.*(.)\\1{2,})";

       testExp = new RegExp(temp);
```

The output I get is :

```
  testExp.test("sss is true")
  testExp.test("ss is false")
  testexp.test("sdsdsd is false") //which should be true.
```

that is my regular expressions take into account only consecutive repeated characters and not others.

Comment: Maybe you'd want to try `/(.+)\1{2,}/.test(temp)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it doesnot consider case like this sdsdsy.

Comment: Right, it does not, because your first example contains *consecutive* repeating chars, and this one does not. Maybe you want [`/(.)(?:.*\1){2,}/`](https://regex101.com/r/DbZsbi/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew so I was looking for regexp which doesnot consider consecuive and work irrespective of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add `.*` before `\1` (to match any 0+ chars other than line break chars) and use the following regex:

```
/(.)(?:.*\1){2,}/
```

Or, if there can be line breaks in the input string:

```
/([\s\S])(?:[\s\S]*\1){2,}/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DbZsbi/2). `[\s\S]` (or `[^]` in JS regex) will match any char while `.` matches any char but a line break char.

**Details**

- `(.)` - capturing group #1 matching any 1 char
- `(?:.*\1){2,}` - 2 or more consecutive occurrences of:

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars
  - `\1` - backreference to Group 1 value (same char as captured in Group 1).

Comment: Stribizew clean and perfect! Thanks for the details.

Answer (score 1):

Try somethink like :

```
var str="sdsdsd";
var hasDuplicates = (/([a-zA-Z]).*?\1/).test(str)        
alert("repeating string "+hasDuplicates);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = 'abcdeaf';
if (text.match(/(.).*\1/) {} else {}
```

Comment: It works on IE and Chrome to me. `if ('1ss1f1h1'.match(/(.).*\1/)) { console.log('ok') }`